# Simple python card game

Tags: python, playing-cards

I'm completely new to python and I have no idea what to do with this program.

I'm trying to build a mini card game that does the following

1. There are six players.
2. At the start of each hand, each player is dealt four cards.
3. For each player, all pairs in their hand are put down. A player gets one point for a pair consisting of two cards with rank less than 10 (with an ace counting as greater than 10). A player gets two points for a payer consisting of two cards with rank 10 or greater. If the hand as two pair, both are put down. The player gets the appropriate points (1 or 2) for the kind of pair.
4. The hand ends after the pairs have been dropped. (Players do not actually enter input or make decisions. I told you it was a boring game.) All cards are returned to the deck, it is reshuffled, and a new hand is started.
5. After each round, the players are listed in descending order of total points. If two players are tied for the same number of points, they are printed with the lowest-numbered player first.
6. After six rounds, the game ends. The first player in the score list (as defined above) wins the game

Output should look like this:

```
Hand 1 deal:
Player 1's hand: 5D 5H KD AS
Player 2's hand: 7D 8D 9C JS
Player 3's hand: 3D 3H 6S 7C
Player 4's hand: 4C 6D 8S TH
Player 5's hand: 4H 5C 7S QC
Player 6's hand: 5S 6H 9H KH

Dropping pairs:
Player 1 dropped 1 pair.
Player 2 dropped no pairs.
Player 3 dropped 1 pair.
Player 4 dropped no pairs.
Player 5 dropped no pairs.
Player 6 dropped no pairs.

Score:
Player 1: 1
Player 3: 1
Player 2: 0
Player 4: 0
Player 5: 0
Player 6: 0
```

The modules I have for this game include.

CARDS.py

```
import string
import random

suits = ['S', 'C', 'D', 'H']
longsuits = ['spades', 'clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts']

ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
longranks = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
        'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']

ranklist = string.join(ranks, "")

ranklookup = {}
for i in range(len(ranks)):
    ranklookup[ranks[i]] = i

suitlookup = {}
for i in range(len(suits)):
    suitlookup[suits[i]] = i

class Card:
    """
    Class to hold information about a single playing card.  The card's rank
    and suit are stored.

    The constructor takes two arguments, the rank and suit of the card.  The
    rank and suit must be values from the ranks and suits list.

    >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
    >>> c2 = Card('K', 'H')
    >>> print c1
    8C
    >>> print c2
    KH
    """

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.__rank = ranklookup[rank]
        self.__suit = suitlookup[suit]

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        """
        Compare two card objects.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> c2 = Card('K', 'H')
        >>> c1<c2
        True
        >>> c1>c2
        False
        >>> c1==c2
        False
        """
        if self.__rank == other.__rank:
            return cmp(self.__suit, other.__suit)
        else:
            return cmp(self.__rank, other.__rank)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Return a two-character string representing the card.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> str(c1)
        '8C'
        """
        return self.shortname()
    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Return a the Python code required to construt the card.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> print repr(c1) .split(".",1)[1]
        Card('8', 'C')
        """
        return "%s.Card('%s', '%s')" % (self.__module__, ranks[self.__rank], suits[self.__suit])

    def suit(self):
        """
        Return a character representing the card's suit.  This will be one of the
        characters from suits.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> c1.suit()
        'C'
        """
        return suits[self.__suit]

    def rank(self):
        """
        Return a character with the card's rank.  This will be one of the
        characters from ranks.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> c1.rank()
        '8'
        """
        return ranks[self.__rank]

    def shortname(self):
        """
        Output a short two-character description of the card.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> c1.shortname()
        '8C'
        """
        return ranks[self.__rank] + suits[self.__suit]

    def longname(self):
        """
        Return a long English description of the card.

        >>> c1 = Card('8', 'C')
        >>> c1.longname()
        'eight of clubs'
        """
        return longranks[self.__rank] + " of " + longsuits[self.__suit]



testhand = [ Card('9', 'H'), Card('6', 'C'), Card('7', 'S'), Card('6', 'D'), Card('A', 'H') ]

def deck():
    """
    Return an *unshuffled* deck of cards (list of card objects).

    >>> d = deck()
    >>> print hand_string(d)
    2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S TS JS QS KS AS 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C TC JC QC KC AC 2D 3D 4D 5D 6D 7D 8D 9D TD JD QD KD AD 2H 3H 4H 5H 6H 7H 8H 9H TH JH QH KH AH
    >>> print len(d)
    52
    """
    d = []
    for suit in range(len(suits)):
        for rank in range(len(ranks)):
            c = Card(ranks[rank], suits[suit])
            d.append(c)

    return d


def small_deck():
    """
    Return a small *unshuffled* deck of cards (list of card objects).  This is
    smaller than a regular deck and can be used for testing.

    >>> d = small_deck()
    >>> print hand_string(d)
    9S TS JS QS KS AS 9C TC JC QC KC AC 9D TD JD QD KD AD 9H TH JH QH KH AH
    >>> print len(d)
    24
    """
    d = []
    for suit in range(len(suits)):
        for rank in [7,8,9,10,11,12]:
            c = Card(ranks[rank], suits[suit])
            d.append(c)

    return d



def start_pair(hand):

    """
        Return index of first card in first pair of the hand.
        The index is for the order the hand has after sorting.
        If there are no pairs, return -1.

        Side effect:  The hand is sorted.
    """
    hand.sort()
    start = -1
    for i in range(len(hand)-1, 0, -1):
        if hand[i].rank() == hand[i-1].rank():
            start = i -1
    return start





def drop_pair(hand):
    """
    Remove a pair from the hand (list of card objects) if possible.  Return
    the new hand and the number of pairs dropped (0 or 1).  A "pair" is two
    cards with the same rank.

    If there is more than one pair, only the first is removed.

    The hand MUST be sorted by rank before this function is called.  This
    can be done with:
        hand.sort()

    >>> testhand.sort()
    >>> print hand_string(testhand)
    6C 6D 7S 9H AH
    >>> newhand, pts = drop_pair(testhand)
    >>> print hand_string(newhand)
    7S 9H AH
    >>> print pts
    1
    """
    newhand = hand[:]
    for i in range(len(newhand)-1):
        if newhand[i].rank() == newhand[i+1].rank():
            del(newhand[i+1])
            del(newhand[i])
            return newhand, 1
    return newhand, 0



def hand_string(hand):
    """
    Create a string that represents the cards in the player's hand.

    >>> hand_string(testhand)
    '6C 6D 7S 9H AH'
    >>> hand_string([])
    ''
    """

    return " ".join( [c.shortname() for c in hand] )


def _test():
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

end of module.

and

```
pointsort.py

'''
    Module to sort players by points and player numbers.  See definition for
    function sortPlayers() for details of sort order.
'''

def playerToSort(p):
    ''' Represent player number such that lower-numbered players sort before higher-numbered '''
    return -p

def playerFromSort(p):
    ''' Extract original player number from playerToSort() representation '''
    return -p

def sortPlayers(playerNum, points):
    ''' Sort players by total points, then by player number within total points.
        Player numbers are sorted such that low-numbered players are highest.

        Returns list of tuples (playerNumber, points), sorted in *increasing* order
        by the two criteria.
    '''
    keys = []
    for n in playerNum:
        keys.append(playerToSort(n))

    order = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        order.append((points[i], keys[i]))

    order.sort()
    result = []
    for i in range(len(order)):
        result.append((playerFromSort(order[i][1]), order[i][0]))

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    points = [3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3]
    number = [2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5]
    order = sortPlayers(number, points)
    # Note that the following prints results in the WRONG order for A4 
    for i in range(len(order)):
        print "Player " + str(order[i][0]) + " had " + str(order[i][1]) + " points."



i was really hoping if someone could help me with the loops that this program needs, especially the point loop system. 
this what i have so far, 

import cards
import random

new = cards.small_deck()

print cards.hand_string(new)
print len(new)


player1 = []
player2 = []
player3 = []
player4 = []
player5 = []
player6 = []
#shuffle the cards
random.shuffle(new)
num = input('How many cards to deal to each player? ')
while num > 0:
        player1.append(new.pop(0))
        player2.append(new.pop(0))
        player3.append(new.pop(0))
        player4.append(new.pop(0))
        player5.append(new.pop(0))
        player6.append(new.pop(0))
        num = num - 1
#prints out 8 cards for each person

print 'the cards remaining in the deck are: '
print len(new)

#sorts player1 cards and removes the pairs
player1.sort()
print "sorted hand for player 1:"
print cards.hand_string(player1)
newplayer1 = []
player1points = 0

newplayer1, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player1)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer1)

#sorts player2 cards
player2.sort()
print "sorted hand for player 2:"
print cards.hand_string(player2)
newplayer2 = []
player2points = 0

newplayer2, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player2)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer2)



#sorts player3 cards
player3.sort()
print "sorted hand for player 3:"
print cards.hand_string(player3)
newplayer3 = []
player3points = 0

newplayer3, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player3)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer3)   


#sorts player4 cards
player4.sort()
print "sorted hand for player 4:"
print cards.hand_string(player4)
newplayer4 = []
player4points = 0

newplayer4, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player4)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer4)


#sorts player5 cards
player5.sort()
print "sorted hand for player 5:"
print cards.hand_string(player5)
newplayer5 = []
player5points = 0

newplayer5, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player5)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer5)

#sorts player6 cards
player6.sort()
print "sorted hand for player 6:"
print cards.hand_string(player6)
newplayer6 = []
player6points = 0

newplayer6, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player6)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer6)
```

I have great troubles with loops and will apreciate any help I can get, thank you in advance

Comment: Please fix the formatting (edit post, see Markdown help). This is very unreadable.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. What programming experience do you have, and what class do you need this for? I'm guessing it's not object-oriented programming

Comment: You need to be more specific about the trouble you have with loops. Also, if you could illustrate the troubles with a short piece of code, you would get answers more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to not use `pointsort.py` at all, which is fine, since I didn't end up needing it for your expected output.

```
# main.py
import cards
import random

deck = cards.small_deck()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.points = 0
        self.hand = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player %d" % self.number

players = [Player(num + 1) for num in xrange(6)]  # create six numbered players
rounds = 6
hand_size = 4

for round_num in xrange(rounds):
    #shuffle the cards
    random.shuffle(deck)
    print "Hand %d deal:" % (round_num + 1)
    # deal cards
    for _ in xrange(hand_size):
        for player in players:
            # draw from the back instead of the front: possibly slightly more efficient
            player.hand.append(deck.pop())

    # sort player cards
    for player in players:
        player.hand.sort()
        print "%s's hand: %s" % (player, cards.hand_string(player.hand))
    print

    print "Dropping pairs:"
    for player in players:
        #removes the pairs
        new_hand, dropped_cards, pairs = cards.drop_pairs(player.hand)
        deck.extend(player.hand)  # realistically we can dump the hand now anyway.
        player.hand = []

        player.points += pairs

        how_many = pairs
        plural = "s"
        if pairs == 0:
            how_many = "no"
        elif pairs == 1:
            plural = ""
        print "%s dropped %s pair%s" % (player, how_many, plural)
    print

    print "Score:"
    for player in players:
        print "%s: %d" % (player, player.points)
    print
```

I also changed drop_pair to drop_pairs, and made it find all of the pairs instead of just one. If it finds three-of-a-kind it's worth 2 points, and four-of-a-kind is worth 3.

```
# in cards.py
def drop_pairs(hand):
    new_hand = hand[:]
    dropped_cards = []
    pairs = 0
    for card1, card2 in zip(hand, hand[1:]):  # look at every two-in-a-row cards
        if card1.rank() == card2.rank():
            try:
                new_hand.remove(card1)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                dropped_cards.append(card1)
            try:
                new_hand.remove(card2)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                dropped_cards.append(card2)
            pairs += 1
    return new_hand, dropped_cards, pairs
```

I didn't look over all of your code, and without more specific guidance than 'help with loops' I can't help too much, but a few things I noticed:

- In python you can iterate directly over a list instead of iterating from 0 to len - 1 and checking the indices. For example:

  ```
  # this will work, but it's not recommended
  for suit in range(len(suits)):
      for rank in range(len(ranks)):
          c = Card(ranks[rank], suits[suit])
          d.append(c)

  # this is much cleaner
  for suit in suits:
      for rank in ranks:
          d.append(Card(rank, suit))
  ```
- However, sometimes you DO want to iterate over a range of consecutive numbers, or you just want some code to run a certain number of times, in which case you can use range (or xrange, which in python 2 is more efficient for large ranges)

  ```
  # don't do this
  while num > 0:
      do_something()
      num = num - 1

  # Do this instead!
  for i in xrange(num):
      do_something()
  ```

Also, if you don't need the 'i' variable for the current number, you can use the name '_', which gets reassigned often and is a good place for junk data.

- You can also nest lists. This is very useful if you're not sure how many lists you're going to have. That is to say, if you have six players:

  ```
  # no no no
  player1 = []
  player2 = []
  player3 = []
  player4 = []
  player5 = []
  player6 = []

  # better...
  players = [[], [], [], [], [], []]

  # yes!
  players = []
  for _ in xrange(6):
      players.append([])

  # There's also a shortcut called List Comprehensions, which allows us
  # to be even more concise with our list definitions.
  players = [[] for _ in xrange(6)]
  ```

The advantage of the latter two examples is that you can easily change how many players there are in the game by changing the number 6, or even using a variable instead. They also cut down on code repetition: your logic for each player dealing with their cards is copy pasted 6 times with only a single number changed between them. This isn't very extensible: if you wanted to add or remove players you would have to add or remove that many repeated blocks from your code. Instead:

```
    # no! bad!
    player1 = []
    player2 = []
    player3 = []
    player4 = []
    player5 = []
    player6 = []

    player1.do_stuff()
    player2.do_stuff()
    player3.do_stuff()
    player4.do_stuff()
    player5.do_stuff()
    player6.do_stuff()

    # much easier!
    for player in players:
        player.do_stuff()
```